# Multi-parent partially mapped crossover (MPPMX) - pseudocode infinite loop?

Tags: python-2.6, genetic-algorithm, crossover

I have following pseudocode:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/ls6NECn.png?1]

**7**: We create an array with bool values (apparently, this is not explained in the paper). We assign the current value (value = index) "true"

**18**: At this point, we could have an array, where all values could be "true" and reached the condition of k = len(parents)
**19-22**: This would create an infinite loop

Am I missing something?

Paper: Multi-parent extension of partially mapped crossover for combinatorial optimization problems.     Chuan-Kang Tinga, , , Chien-Hao Sub, , Chung-Nan Leeb,

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417409006800

//EDIT: HERE GOES MY CODE PYTHON-2.6

```
def MappingListDetermination(parents):
    mapping_list = []
    startparent = parents[random.sample(xrange(0, len(parents)), 1)[0]]
    ptr = random.sample(xrange(0, len(startparent)), 1)[0]
    temp_value = startparent[ptr]
    boolean = [False] * listSize
    for j in xrange(0,len(startparent)):
        mapping_list.append(temp_value)
        boolean[temp_value-1] = True
        arr = random.sample(xrange(0, n), n)
        if arr[0] == parents.index(startparent):
          arr[0] = arr[random.sample(xrange(1, len(arr)), 1)[0]]
        endparent = parents[arr[0]]
        ptr = endparent.index(temp_value)
        k = 0
        while((boolean[startparent[ptr]-1] is True) and (k is not len(parents)-1)):
            k = k + 1           
            startparent = parents[arr[k]]
        if((boolean[startparent[ptr]-1] is True) and (k is len(parents)-1)):
            while(boolean[startparent[ptr]-1] is True ):
                startparent = parents[random.sample(xrange(0, len(parents)), 1)[0]]
                ptr = startparent[random.sample(xrange(0, len(startparent)), 1)[0]]-1
        temp_value = startparent[ptr]ere
```

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded a copy of the paper and skimmed over it. It does look interesting but you are correct that `boolean` isn't defined. In context, it seems to be an array whose length is the number of parents which keeps track of which parents have been chosen at a particular stage in the algorithm. Thus -- it starts with all entries `false` and after line 7 in the pseudocode only one entry is `true` -- thus there is no danger of an infinite loop (given that there are at least three parents).

As pseudocode goes -- this isn't very useful. I would recommend almost ignoring the pseudocode and concentrating instead on the surrounding discussion and diagrams and try to implement it using a language like Python where you should be able to get a working function which is shorter than the article`s pseudocode.

Comment: So I posted my python code and spotted one mistake instantly. My 'boolean' array had the size of an individual parent rather than the size of 'parents'.
I am still a bit confused. I thought parents[startparent, ptr] is an access of the parents array on one element and on a specific chromosome in that element. Like you would do in a 2D Array e.g array[val1][val2]. So temp_value would be the chromosome value which ranges from 1-9 which could result in an out-of-bound exception at line 7 in some point.